# how can I get my paragraphs on differents lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnHkc.jpg)
When I use vscode word-wrap (cmd+Z) on my paragraph I get only one line, so how can I put them on different lines?

Comment: use a formatter and specify a max line length

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Shift + Alt + F. On macOS Shift + Option + F. On Linux Ctrl + Shift + I.